# Proof that $K[X, Y]/(f)$ is an integral ring if $f$ is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be a field and consider the polynomial ring $K[X, Y]$. If $f\in K[X, Y]$ is irreducible, then $K[X, Y]/(f)$ is an integral ring.

How do you prove this? I know how to do this in the case of one variable but I have never treated such quotients with several variables.

Thank you.

EDIT
I just finished the proof, thank you all for your help !

Comment: "Integral domain" is more common.

Comment: You should still accept an answer if any of them are helpful at all (and I think they are).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ring $K[X,Y]$ is known to be a unique factorization domain, so every irreducible element is also prime (you find the proof in any algebra textbook). Hence an irreducible polynomial generates a prime ideal.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\ K[X] $ is a UFD since it has a Euclidean division algorithm. Generally UFD $D\Rightarrow$ UFD $D[Y].\,$ Combining we deduce $\,R = K[X,Y] \cong (K[X])[Y]$ is a UFD, therefore the irreducible $f$ is prime, hence $\, R/f\,$ is a domain.

Why is UFD $D\Rightarrow$ UFD $D[Y]$ true? The usual proof uses Gauss's Lemma. However that obscures the essence of the matter. Suppose we have a domain where every nonzero nonunit factors into irreducibles. To show it is a UFD requires showing that every irreducible is prime. Suppose we already know that some subset $S$ of irreducibles are prime. Then we can simplify matters by "ignoring" elements of $S$ in factorizations. This we achieve by forcing them to be units, i.e. by working in the subring of its quotient field obtained by adjoing $1/s$ for all $\,s\in S.\,$ It is quite easy to show that this enlarged ring is a UFD $\iff$ the original ring is a UFD.

Now we apply this to $\,D[Y],\,$ with $S$ being all primes of the UFD  $D$. Adjoining their inverses yields $F[Y]$ where $F$ is the fraction field of $D$. But this is a UFD, having a Euclidean division algorithm. Therefore, by the prior paragraph, we conclude that $D[Y]$ is a UFD too.

This is sometimes called "Nagata's trick", but I suspect that the basic idea is much older. The method of adjoining inverses to kill uninteresting objects is a special case of  [localization.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring)

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

++ If $\;R\;$ is a commutative unitary ring, then the ideal $\;I\le R\;$ is prime iff the quotient ring $\;R/I\;$ is an integral domain.

++ A principal ideal $\;\langle f\rangle\le K[X,Y]\;$ is prime iff $\;f\in K[X,Y]\;$ is irreducible